# Guzzle Curl Failing With Connection Refused

Tags: php, curl, localhost, vagrant, guzzle

I am trying to figure out why my Guzzle request is throwing a number 7 error when cURLing.

Here is my guzzle code:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new Client([
    'base_url' => ['http://mysite.local:8000/api/v1.0.0', []],
    'defaults' => [
        'proxy'   => 'http://mysite.local:8000'
    ]
]);

$request = $client->createRequest('GET', 'simplecontroller/index', [
    'query' => ['foo' => 'bar']
]);

$response = $client->send($request);

var_dump($response); // <-- is not happening becauase:
```

It is failing on `CurlAdapter::send()`.  The cURL request is throwing an error, and thus being handled by the `handleError` method.  Here is the error message:

```
string 'Failed to connect to mysite.local port 8000: Connection refused'
```

Any idea of what might need to change?  I am working on a project that talks to an API, and that api code also happens to be in development as well on my local machine.  I am also using Vagrant Homestead if that helps.  As far as I can tell, it should be possible to cURL to a local url for testing purposes.  If it is not, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: mysite.loca is really a valid domain name in your system? An the port number is correct?

Comment: Yes it's in my /etc/hosts file.  127.0.0.1 mysite.local and the port is 8000

Comment: Hm try it with the IP too, maybe there's something with the resolve.

Comment: So after tinkering around with it I took out the :8000 and it connected, but I'm not getting any data returned from the url.  But the $response gives me a status code of 200

Comment: The default port is the 80 which is the HTTP port, I don't know your current setup, but that connected now to your default webserver.

Comment: I'm using Vagrant Homestead on a mac with local development URL's resembling the one in the example above.